# Hosting project using Firebase

Tags: reactjs, firebase, api-key

I have a question, I made a website using Firebase database and React, so I use an API KEY.

Now I want to host this website online but the problem is that I don't know how to hide my API KEY from my code.

I used a .env file, but how does it work in production then? How do the production ready code knows where to access the key?

Edit:

The answer is there:
[Is it safe to expose Firebase apiKey to the public?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37482366/is-it-safe-to-expose-firebase-apikey-to-the-public/37484053#37484053)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37482366/is-it-safe-to-expose-firebase-apikey-to-the-public/37484053#37484053?

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen thanks ! I didn't find this post before ! Have a nice day